# Agregar en un Mysqli un valor diferente al indicado por el select

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

chicos poseo el siguiente conflicto:

Tengo dentro de un form la siguiente linea de codigo:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="monto">Seleccione Monto</label>
<select class="custom-select" id="monto_mensualidad" name="monto_mensualidad" value="';
echo $monto_mensualidad;
echo '" required >
<option value="">Seleccione:</option>';
monto_mensualidad(); 
echo '</select> <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe Seleccionar el monto de su transferencia.</div>
</div>
```

La function `monto_mensualidad()` es la siguiente, en esta function se selecciona el monto almacenado en la Base de Datos asi como el nombre del plan al que corresponde dicho plan, es decir un plan de valor 200 el plan es basico y el plan de valor 500 el plan es Avanzado y asi tal cual se lo muestra al usuario que ve el select:

```
function monto_mensualidad(){
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM monto_mensualidad ORDER BY monto";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    while ($valores_mensualidad = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$valores_mensualidad[monto].'">'.$valores_mensualidad[monto].' BsS Plan '.$valores_mensualidad[afiliacion] .'</option>';
    }
}
```

Por otra parte dentro de la function `generar_pago_mensualidad()` que es donde se guarda la informacion en mi base de datos tengo lo siguiente:

```
function generar_pago_mensualidad(){
    global $db, $username, $usua, $mes_de_pago_actual;

    // Datos recibidos del Formulario
    $monto              = $_POST['monto_mensualidad'];
    $banco_emisor       = $_POST['banco_emisor'];
    $banco_destino      = $_POST['banco_destino'];
    $nro_transf         = $_POST['nro_transf'];
    $ci_nro_cuenta      = $_POST['ci_nro_cuenta'];
    $fecha_transf       = $_POST['fecha_transf'];
    $ci_nro_cuenta      = $_POST['ci_nro_cuenta'];


    $status_pedido ="PENDIENTE";
    $concepto = "MENSUALIDAD";

    $verf = "SELECT nro_transf FROM pagos WHERE usuario = '$usua' AND nro_transf = '$nro_transf'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $verf);
    $rows =  mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($rows>0){
        $_SESSION['success']  = "Lo sentimos, el numero de transferencia ya existe.<br>";
        //mysqli_close($db);
    } else {

$query = "INSERT INTO pagos (id, user, monto, concepto, mes_de_pago, afiliacion, banco_origen, banco_destino, nro_transf, ci_nro_cuenta, fecha_transf, status_pedido) 
VALUES(null, '$user', '$monto', '$concepto', '$mes_de_pago_actual', '$afiliacion', '$banco_emisor', '$banco_destino', '$nro_transf', '$ci_nro_cuenta', '$fecha_transf', '$status_pedido')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $resultado_ingreso = mysqli_query($db, $query) or mysqli_error($db); 
    $_SESSION['success']  = "Se ha registrado su pedido de manera Exitosa.<br>";
    //header('location: pedidos.php');
    $email = $_SESSION['user']['email'];
    $nombre = $_SESSION['user']['nombre'];
    $asunto = "ASUNTO";
    $cuerpo = "Hola $nombre: <br/><br/>
    Usted ha registrado Pago del mes $mes_de_pago_actual de manera exitosa por un monto de $monto BsS <br>
    Desde $banco_emisor hacia $banco_destino <br>
    Numero de operacion $nro_transf <br>
    Efectuado el $fecha_transf. <br/>";
    enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo); 
    $_SESSION['success']  .= "Hemos enviado Un correo con el resumen de su pedido";
    //header('location: pedidos.php');
    //header('Refresh: 10; URL=pedidos.php');
    }
}
```

Mi duda es como puedo lograr que mi function reconozca el valor de mi variable `$afiliacion` asi como lo hace en la `function monto_mensualidad()` es decir que si la persona en el select selecciona 200 Bs Plan Basico entonces en la function generar_pago_mensualidad() el valor de mi variable `$monto             = $_POST['monto_mensualidad'];` sea 200 y el valor de mi variable $afiliacion sea BASICO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podría darte 2 opciones.

Uno: Poner en el value de los options del select

```
echo '<option value="'.$valores_mensualidad[monto].'_'.$valores_mensualidad[afiliacion] .'">'.$valores_mensualidad[monto].' BsS Plan '.$valores_mensualidad[afiliacion] .'</option>';
```

En esta linea lo que se haría sería enviar el valor y el tipo de afiliación concatenados con un guión al piso y luego en tu variable php le harías un explode para obtener ambos valores de nuevo.

```
$monto = $_POST['monto_mensualidad'];
$monto = explode('_', $monto);
$afiliacion = $monto[1];
$monto = $monto[0];
```

De esta manera envías ambos datos en el formulario

Dos: la segunda opción sería en donde recibes el formulario con php hacer de nuevo una consulta a base de datos buscando la afiliación por monto.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM monto_mensualidad WHERE monto = $monto";
$results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda!